# Can I use a USD travel card in Europe

Tags: europe, payment-cards, poland, atms

I've an existing VISA USD travel card.  Now I'm traveling to Poland.

Can I use this card in ATMs there?

Comment: Is that a VISA? MC? Something else?

Comment: Sorry it's a visa travel card in which i can load money before my trip

Comment: You should be able to use it anywhere where you can use a visa, including ATMs. If it's a visa electron some terminals might reject it but ATMs should be OK. In any case, there could be additional charges for ATM withdrawal or currency exchange.

Comment: @Annoyed: actually, it's not necessarily true that you can use a foreign VISA card at any ATM that accepts VISA cards. For example, in Japan 10 years ago it was common for ATMs to accept only domestic credit cards. This may have changed in the meantime, but it's a valid concern.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Maybe but that's not what the question or my comment were about. My point is that a visa USD travel card should work like a regular USD visa card. Also, the OP was not asking about Japan, I did not want to imply that it wasn't a valid concern and “should” does not suggest any sort of absolute certainty. I am sure there could be many corner cases or exceptions, that's why it was only a comment…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Poland VISA cards are very widely used - you can pay in shops, you can use ATMs. E.g. I can use my VISA card, issued in Poland with polish currency (zł/PLN), in another countries with different currency: pay using it or get money from ATMs.

I'm writing this to show that your need is nothing special in Poland and probably you shouldn't have any problems. But - as was pointed by Flimzy - you should ask in your bank and it will be only one, 100% sure answer.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to answer this question conclusively is to call the bank which issued the card.  There should be a phone number on the back of the card which you can call.  You should ask a few key questions:

1. Will the card work in your destination country/ies?
2. Do you need to inform the bank of your travel plans and dates? (Many banks will notice foreign transactions and trigger an anti-fraud lock on your card if they don't know you're expecting to use your card in a new location, which can be quite annoying)
3. Will there be additional transaction fees or exchange rate fees for foreign transactions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer , as per my own experience after asking the question

1.Will the card work in other countries other than the USA
    Yes, there is no difference, except the exchange rate is applicable and without any other extra fee
2.Do you need to tell the bank about your travel ?
    Yes, infact when you buy the card first time , they will ask for visa and travel documents including an airticket

**One useful additional info to save your money**

Some ATMs use something called "Dynamic currency conversion" (Following info is  copied from a bank's expanation)

What is Dynamic Currency Conversion?

In certain countries, the acquiring banks may choose to activate the feature of "Dynamic Currency Conversion" on their ATMs and POS Machine network. As per this facility, the ATM/POS machine identifies the Travel Currency Card as a card issued from a foreign country and prompts the customer to transact in their "home currency" (in case of Indians, this would be Indian Rupees). If a customer selects the "home currency/INR" option, additional cross-currency charges are levied by the acquiring bank (the bank that runs the ATM/POS machine).

Can I use the DCC option at the time of transaction?

The Travel Currency Card is purchased and loaded with the purpose of using the card in the respective foreign currency, the customer must avoid selecting any option that prompts for a change in usage currency to avoid any adverse exchange rate.
The "dynamic currency conversion" feature may appear with differing terminology depending on the overseas bank.
Card issuing bank is not responsible for any "dynamic currency conversion" related charges and will not be able to refund any such charges in case they are levied on account of wrong usage of card.